# Hiding listbox option in IE with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I finished some jQuery code to manipulate showing/hiding of listbox items and then found it doens' work in IE 8.  This simplified example(assume there's a listbox on the page) works fine for hiding all options of a listbox in Firefox, but not for IE.  Any ideas why this doesn't work?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" /> 
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("option").hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide option elements in Internet Explorer.  You need to remove them instead:

```
$('option').detach();
```

Comment: Apparently because `display:none` style isn't recognized by IE for option elements.